What obfuscation techniques are used in this JavaScript code snippet?
So I am working on a CTF titled "Javascript - Native code" on root-me.org, I couldn't find much explanation on what kind of obfuscation this is anywhere. I am NOT looking for a solution on how to solve the challenge as I have already solved it, I am just curious as to what obfuscation method was used for this code snippet. Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated!
The Code Snippet
<script>
É=-~-~[],ó=-~É,Ë=É<<É,þ=Ë+~[];Ì=(ó-ó)[Û=(''+{})[É+ó]+(''+{})[ó-É]+([].ó+'')[ó-É]+(!!''+'')[ó]+({}+'')[ó+ó]+(!''+'')[ó-É]+(!''+'')[É]+(''+{})[É+ó]+({}+'')[ó+ó]+(''+{})[ó-É]+(!''+'')[ó-É]][Û];Ì(Ì((!''+'')[ó-É]+(!''+'')[ó]+(!''+'')[ó-ó]+(!''+'')[É]+((!''+''))[ó-É]+([].$+'')[ó-É]+'\''+''+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó-ó)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(É)+'\\'+(É+É)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+É)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó+ó)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+ó)+(É+É)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó+ó)+'\\'+(É+É)+(þ)+'\\'+(É+ó)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\'')())()
</script>

My Research

Did a bit of research on Native Code, to my understanding "native code refers to code or functionality that is built into the JavaScript engine itself, as opposed to user-defined functions or third-party libraries. When a function or method is part of JavaScript's core (like methods on objects such as Array, String, Object, etc.), it is often implemented in the engine's underlying language (e.g., C++ in the case of V8) and not directly accessible for modification.".


If the browser is able to execute it, then it's obviously not enciphered.  "LSPK90 clockwise" is an encoding for text, not for code.

It's just some clever variable naming and use of standard JavaScript operators. É evaluates to 2, ó to 3, Ë to 8, and so on. Nothing to do with encryption.

The variables are used to create ASCII character equivalents, and if we look at the string of these at the end we find they are: a=prompt('Entrez le mot de passe');if(a=='toto123lol'){alert('bravo');}else{alert('fail...'); So, the obfuscation is fun but very easily cracked!

This obfuscation has nothing to do with "native code" in the sense of the definition you found.

...and even more subtle methods of getting a character are used nearer the start. For example: ([].ó+'')[ó-É] gives the letter n as  ([].ó+'') gives undefined and ó-É gives 1 - and n is the second (ie with index 1) letter in undefined. All these shennanigans just result in the word 'constructor'.

Thank you for submitting a well written question on your first attempt.  The only issue is that what you are asking is off topic on Stack Overflow.  I'd recommend asking your question on Cryptography

Also, a small note: the words I am just curious usually implies you aren't that interested in the answer, and discourages others from posting.  Read How do I ask a good question?, and more importantly read how to create a Minimal, Reproducible example

@LordElrond the mapping of characters here is so trivial that I’m not sure it would qualify as real cryptography!  At first I too thought the question was off topic for SO but now I’m not so sure as it’s basically trying to understand how that code results in the JavaScript which is runnable. The code has been given.
